# Select max win series: sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MySQL

I have table, where i store user_matches and it result:

```
n_match  id_user  id_score
1        55       1
1        66       0
```

This mean, 'user with id=55 win match with id=1 to user with id=66'.

So, we have 10, 100, 1000 matches, where user win or lose to opponents:

```
n_match  id_user  id_score
1        55       1 (win)
1        66       0
2        55       0 (lose)
2        77       1
3        55       1 (win)
3        77       0
4        55       1 (win)
4        77       0
5        55       1 (win)
5        77       0
```

Ok. As u can see, user win 3 matches without losing (win series)- and that's what i need from my query.

Question: How could i get from this table the longest series of won matches? Is it possible without looping on sql side or server side- just from query?

Thx.

**Edit:** One of solution i just now understand,- to get all matches as string like 001010101111010101011, then split it into array of strings with separator '0' -> [1, 1, 1, 1111, ...] and just take the longest string length.

But in this case i have to write server side code =\ That's not good, but mb the fastest.

Comment: It's *way way* less complicated to just query this out in the proper order and process it in a loop in PHP.  To do it otherwise (without, as you request, looping in a mysql function) is to essentially manually create a loop without a loop in SQL, it gets huge and unwieldy and *impossible* to maintain and you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to calculate the cumulative number of losses for any match.  For a sequence of wins, this value is constant.  You can then use group by to get the length of the longest such sequence.

This version of the query is database-neutral.  It uses subqueries to get the counts:

```
select user_id, max(NumWinsInRow)
from (select user_id, cumlosses, count(*)-1 as NumWinsInRow
      from (select m.*,
                   (select sum(case when id_score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) from user_matches m2 where m2.id_user = m.id_user and m2.n_match <= m.n_match
                   ) as CumLosses
            from user_matches m
           ) t
      group by cumlosses, user_id
     ) t
group by user_id
```

This query should run faster if you have an index on `user_matches(id_user, n_math, id_score)`.